# Возврат значения функции в качестве аргумента для другой

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.Возможно этот вопрос покажется банальным,но я бы хотел детально узнать ,что и как происходит здесь:

```
$id = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_GET['id'])));
```

Результат я знаю,знаю что каждая из функций делает,но я бы хотел узнать как вычисляются аргументы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обратном порядке вложенности (т.е. функции выполняются в обратном порядке вложенности, сначала trim, потом strip_tags, потом strtolower, результат каждой возвращается в следующую). В яваскрипте даже может прокатить создание внешней функции внутри функции, которая должна вернуть аргумент.